# How can I output an entire git repo to a single file?

Tags: git, git-diff

I created a git repo and I want the entire git repo with all commits as a single patch file.

I've tried many SO posts, but couldn't find any suitable solution anywhere.

Comment: What exactly do you need to do with the result?  What kind of system is it for?  Be specific. Just cloning the repo is going to be by far the most compact representation.

Comment: So "patch" was actually the full repo history in your case?

Comment: @VonC: There wasn't any "patch" as such. I wanted my entire repo as a text file.

Comment: @PalakArora excellent. did you choose bundle (to get all the commits), or just archive (to get the HEAD content in a zip file)?

Comment: @VonC: I tried out another method as I've posted it over here. I've upvoted your answer. :) Thanks.

Comment: But your method is about a patch, not the full content of your repo?!

Comment: @VonC: You may rename the file as a `.txt` file also. I just wanted it in text format. It outputs the entire repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, I tried out another method on my own, I thought of posting it here. It was exactly what I needed.

```
git log --pretty=format:"%H - %an, %ad : %s" --author "<your name>" --after="2014-05-19 00:00:00" --before="2014-08-18 00:00:00" -p --no-merges > ~/<path to some folder>/myrepo.patch
```

Comment: Note that a repo with merge commits will not be reconstructible from the output of this command, which ignores merges.

Answer (score 7):

In order to create a single patch encapsulating the whole repository, you need to diff the current HEAD against the empty tree. Such a tree is available in git under the SHA1 `4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904` (This is the SHA1 that you would get if you created the empty tree by emptying the index and issuing `git write-tree`. Every git repository has one.)

Therefore the command you are looking for is:

```
git diff --binary 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904..HEAD
```

The `--binary` option makes sure that binary content will be included in the diff, and that the file names will not be abbreviated.

Comment: Seriously? downvoted *again*? Could we at least wait for the OP to clarify the exact use case? I will delete my answer if Palak confirms that diff was the right answer.

Comment: @VonC Why insist on providing an answer that doesn't answer the question? While the OP's wish to obtain a "single patch file" is admittedly strange, I don't see how either of your interpretations fits the term. You have been on SO far longer than me, and should know better than to scoff at an occasional downvote. (I won't even comment the practice of deleting an answer and then resubmitting the exact same one.)

Answer (score 2):

While [user4815162342](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1600898/user4815162342)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25469180/6309) is technically the right solution (upvoted), [Palak Arora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2490990/palak-arora)'s question about "an entire git repo with all commits as a single patch file" could be interpreted differently.

Here are two other possibilities, pending Palak's feedback:

---

If by patch "with all commits" you mean the full history of a git repo as *one* file, you could consider [**creating a bundle**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1251717/6309).
It is a single file which acts actually as a Git repo: you can fetch or pull or clone from that file;

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git bundle create /tmp/foo-all --all
```

---

If your "patch" is actually the full content of the current repo, you can also use [`git archive`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5392247/6309)

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git archive -o /tmp/foo.tar --format=tar .
```

---

In both cases, they differ from the classic patch in that you wouldn't use a bundle or an archive to "apply" that "patch" on an existing code base, but rather to rebuild quickly said code base from scratch.